# Linker error xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, target

I have added a project into my project and I set header search path and Target dependency but When I try to use a class from the imported project It says the following error while building...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyImportedViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
```

Comment: Make sure `MyImportedViewController.m` is targeted properly.

Comment: Which is a file from another sub project. When I add that sub project I checked my super project check box

Comment: @rmaddy before that I need a clarification, Can I import a sub project into my super project with out creating static library?